# Need numbering above each column of a python grid

Tags: python-3.5, grid-layout

I need to modify a program the program 'x' so that it outputs the original grid, but each row and column is labeled with it's respective number. i.e. column 1 has a first, row 1 has a 1 first. I have figured out how to put numbering in front of the rows, but cannot figure out how to modify the program so that the columns are numbered.

'x'

```
import random
aGrid = []
SIZE = 10
for r in range (0,SIZE,1):
    aGrid.append ([])
    for c in range (0,SIZE,1):
        element = random.randint(0,9)
        aGrid[r].append (element)
for r in range (0,SIZE,1):
    for c in range (0,SIZE,1):
        print(aGrid[r][c], end="")
    print()
```

Here is my attempt at getting numbering in front of the rows

```
import random
aGrid = []
SIZE = 11

for r in range (0,SIZE - 1,1):
    aGrid.append ([])
    aGrid[r].append (r )
    aGrid[r].append (" ")
    for c in range (0,SIZE + 1,1):
        element = random.randint(0,9)
        aGrid[r].append (element)

for r in range (0,SIZE - 1,1):
    for c in range (0,SIZE + 1,1):
        print(aGrid[r][c], end="")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change `aGrid`. Just print the row and column numbers in the print loop:

```
import random

aGrid = []
SIZE = 10

for r in range (SIZE):
    aGrid.append ([])
    for c in range (SIZE):
        element = random.randint(0,9)
        aGrid[r].append (element)
print(" ", end="")
for c in range (SIZE):
    print(c, end="")
print()
for i, r in enumerate(range(SIZE)):
    print(i, end="")
    for c in range(SIZE):
        print(aGrid[r][c], end="")
    print()
```

Output:

```
 0123456789
01958724133
17006217440
21488953544
35615572045
49849348546
54207744418
63316678723
76651582077
85713263320
91939404287
```

A version that starts counting from 1 and has some spaces for better readability:

```
import random

aGrid = []
SIZE = 10

for r in range (SIZE):
    aGrid.append ([])
    for c in range (SIZE):
        element = random.randint(0,9)
        aGrid[r].append (element)
print("  ", end=" ")
for c in range (1, SIZE + 1):
    print(c, end=" ")
print()
for i, r in enumerate(range(SIZE), 1):
    print('{:2d}'.format(i), end=" ")
    for c in range(SIZE):
        print(aGrid[r][c], end=" ")
    print()
```

Output:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
 1 3 0 4 6 3 9 3 3 6 3 
 2 5 6 1 6 6 3 2 5 6 1 
 3 6 9 0 5 0 7 1 1 7 7 
 4 7 4 3 9 0 9 1 0 7 8 
 5 5 1 1 1 1 7 1 4 4 8 
 6 4 5 8 1 6 3 6 2 8 6 
 7 4 1 0 5 7 4 5 6 6 4 
 8 4 5 5 4 3 3 0 9 2 1 
 9 3 6 7 0 0 9 5 8 5 9 
10 3 1 2 3 5 0 1 6 2 9
```